# Delete specific indices from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
a = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg']
```

I want to remove specific indices such:

```
del a[1,3:5]
```

But keeps getting:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

How can I manage it?

Comment: can you share what your output list should look like ?

Comment: you want to remove item at index `1` and from `3` to `5` ?

Comment: Make sure that they are separated by commas.

Comment: in list you can't mix together `a[1]` and `a[3:5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use this syntax, and so without paying attention to the shift in index:

```
a = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg']

remove_list = ['1','3:5']

index_list = []

for elem in remove_list:
    if ":" not in elem:
        index_list.append(int(elem))
    else:
        for i in range(int(elem.split(":")[0]),int(elem.split(":")[1])):
            index_list.append(i)

for i in index_list:
    a[i] = ""

a = [x for x in a if x]

print (a)
```

Output:

```
['aa', 'cc', 'ff', 'gg']
```

Using:

```
a = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg']

remove_list = ['1','3:5']

index_list = []

for elem in remove_list:
    if ":" not in elem:
        index_list.append(int(elem))
    else:
        #Last range index + 1
        for i in range(int(elem.split(":")[0]),int(elem.split(":")[1])+1):
            index_list.append(i)

for i in index_list:
    a[i] = ""

a = [x for x in a if x]

print (a)
```

Will output:

```
['aa', 'cc', 'gg']
```

Instead.

Comment: Can you show me how to use the second option you gave with the two variables: 'a' and 'remove_list' you described?

Comment: See my edit ;). I included the whole code

Comment: Thanks! the one-linear before your edit was more elegant though. cheers

Comment: not optimized at all, sort array of index, take array of index by the end then just apply standard del function. try to think better before answering :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just do (You need two deletes):

```py
del a[1]
del a[2:4] #To account for the shift in index
```

This is will output:

```py
['aa', 'cc', 'gg']
```

Comment: If the PO intends to do these two `del` in one shot on the original list, then the expected results will be different.  So it's not clear this is what he wants.  (maybe right or not exactly)

Answer (score 2):

you need to do it twice (also, to keep it simpler, make sure that you delete larger indices before smaller ones)

```py
del a[3:5]
del a[1]
```

Comment: Except for the small shift in syntax, this is basically the same as the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one-liner:

```py
A = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg']

A = [x for i, x in enumerate(A) if i not in (1, 3, 4)]  # x is the item
```

Output is what you would expect:

```
# Note. range(3:5)  is 3 and 4 only. 5 is excluded
['aa', 'cc', 'ff', 'gg']
```

Comment: I suggest this minor simplification: `a = [x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i not in (1, 3, 4)]`

Answer (score 0):

Would this serve the purpose?

```
slices_to_delete = [(1, 2), (3, 5)]
for s in slices_to_delete:
    del a[slice(*s)]
```